# How do you check if the values of every variable in an object is the same in Javascript/AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

Okay, say I have a `$scope.object = {};` and in this object I have various variables like such;

```
$scope.object.a = 0;
$scope.object.b = 0;
$scope.object.c = 0;
$scope.object.d = 0;
```

so the display would be `object = { a : 0, b : 0, c : 0, d : 0 }`

Now I have a set of code that sets certain values from 0 to 1 based on some checkboxes. So say what I have now is

```
$scope.object.a = 1;
$scope.object.b = 1;
$scope.object.c = 1;
$scope.object.d = 0;
```

Here's the tricky part for me, how do i get my `$scope.object` to fetch all the variables with a value of 1 only?

Sorry if the question is not too clear, but I'm trying my best to explain it, cheers! :D

Comment: What do you mean with "fetch"? What would you like to achieve?

Comment: Have your tried anything? *Hint:* `for..in`

Comment: yeah [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: by fetch i mean i would like to check every variable that has a value of 1 and push it into an array later on to filter out some data, but what i need is to get every variable that has the value of 1. @ChristianZosel

Comment: instance method that checks all it's variables and prints them out. or if you want the variables and their values return hash map or if just the values array.

call method `$scope.object.checkVal();`

Comment: tried for..in, doesn't work for my case, sorry i didn't mention it earlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate on the object to get the keys which match your value.

```
function getAllKeys(object, value) {
  keys = [];
  for(i in object) {
   if(object[i] === value) keys.push(i);
  }
  return keys;
}
// ....

$scope.object.a = 1;
$scope.object.b = 1;
$scope.object.c = 1;
$scope.object.d = 0;

getAllKeys($scope.object, 1); // ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 2):

a little example :

```
  $scope.object = {};

  $scope.object.a = 1;
  $scope.object.b = 1;
  $scope.object.c = 1;
  $scope.object.d = 0;

  // if you want an object with only element equal to 1
  var resObj = {};
  // if you want an array of element name equal to 1 in object
  var resArray  = [];
  for(var i in $scope.object){
    if($scope.object[i]==1){
      resObj[i]=1;
      resArray.push(i);
    }
  }
  console.log(resObj);
  console.log(resArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
var obj = {a:1,a:1,a:1,a:0};

for(var i in obj){
    if(obj[i]==0){
        delete obj[i];
        }
    }

console.log(obj); //gives the desired output
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will do the magic,

```
var yourArray= [];    
Object.keys($scope.object).forEach(function(key){
  if($scope.object[key]===1){
   yourArray.push(key);
 }
})
```